# In SQL Server 2008, how to write query to get top 10 records in group wise and I want to display that in single row column like pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

- `reccod = 1` indicates note
- `reccod = 2` indicates terms and condition

These are my table structures; from this I want to get output as

```
ponumb column1   column2   column3   column4   column5  ... column 11  col12
8615   note po 1 note po 2 note po 3 note po 4 note po 5 .. terms&cond1 t&2
```

Sample data:

```
PONUMB  RECCOD  SRLNUB  DESCRP
------------------------------------
8615    1           1   NOTE PO 1
8615    1           2   NOTE PO 2
8615    1           3   NOTE PO 3
8615    1           4   NOTE PO 4
8615    1           5   NOTE PO 5
8615    1           6   NOTE PO 6
8615    1           7   NOTE PO 7
8615    1           8   NOTE PO 8
8615    1           9   NOTE PO 9
8615    1           10  NOTE PO 10
8615    1           11  NOTE PO 11
8615    1           12  NOTE PO 12
8615    2           1   TERMS AND CONDITION 1
8615    2           2   TERMS AND CONDITION 2
8615    2           3   TERMS AND CONDITION 3
8615    2           4   TERMS AND CONDITION 4
8615    2           5   TERMS AND CONDITION 5
8615    2           6   TERMS AND CONDITION 6
8615    2           7   TERMS AND CONDITION 7
8615    2           8   TERMS AND CONDITION 8
```

Comment: In SQL Server 2008 am using

Comment: My desired result is mentioned in first two lines like that i want result

Comment: dont use pivot and row_number concept because it wont support in lower version of sql server..

Comment: **SHOW US** what you've tried so far! We'll be glad to help if you have problems with your code - we will **not** just write the whole code for you, however.....

Comment: SELECT PONUMB AS [PO Number],SRLNUB AS [Serial Number],[Note1] = COALESCE((CASE WHEN SRLNUB = 1 AND RECCOD = 1 THEN DESCRP END),''),[Terms and Condition1] = COALESCE((CASE WHEN SRLNUB = 1 AND RECCOD = 2 THEN DESCRP END),'') FROM INPONVEW WHERE SRLNUB IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

Comment: I have used case statement to perform this but am not getting the result in single line.its coming like diagonal result..

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create 2 seprate pivots, one for Note and one for Terms then use this query

```
select * from 
(select ponumb from table group by ponumb) as masterTable
left outer join (pivotqueryNotes) as Notes on notes.ponumb = masteratable.Ponumb
left outer join (pivotqueryTerms) as Terms on terms.ponumb = masteratable.Ponumb
```